# Cause of -[NSConcreteMutableData bytes]

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone tell me the general cause of this issue `-[NSConcreteMutableData bytes]:` message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f7bce0

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an instance of `NSMutableData` that you have (accidentally?) released. It got deallocated. Yet, you still have a pointer to it and you try to call a method on that dead object.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling a deallocated instance to do something but it cant be done because it is deallocated ;)

You are probably deallocating the instance before calling that particular method.
I suggest looking into the place where you deallocate the instance and try to delay it until you are truly done with it.